# what is the formula for this function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

I've been thinking about the differences in numbers so for example:

$\begin{array}{ccccccc} &&&0&&&\\ &&1&&1&&\\&1&&2&&3&\\0&&1&&3&&6
\end{array}$

or with absolute differences:

$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
&&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots\\
&&1&&0&&2&&2\\
&1&&2&&2&&4&&2\\
2&&3&&5&&7&&11&&13
\end{array}$

so I found this and I wanted to know if this has an actual mathematical formula:

$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
&&&&\vdots\\
&&&3&\cdots&\vdots\\
&&2&&5&\cdots&\vdots\\
&1&&3&&8&\cdots&\vdots\\
0&&1&&4&&12&\cdots
\end{array}$

and the sequence continues  0, 1, 4, 12, 32, 80, 192, 448, 1024, 2304, 5120, 11264, 24576, 53248, 114688, 245760,... If you couldn't tell what I was doing to generate them the first diagonal going up from the 0 increased by one. I wasn't able to find the formula, but I have found some other diagonals have properties like, the second (1,3,5...) is the odd numbers, all of those diagonals are linear.

Comment: I recommend reformatting this with `\begin{array}\end{array}` to improve readability.  See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to type in MathJax here.  Example: `$\begin{array}{ccc} & & 0\\ & 1&1\\ 1&2&3\end{array}$` creates the output $\begin{array}{ccc} & & 0\\ & 1&1\\ 1&2&3\end{array}$

Comment: @JMoravitz is there something similar so I can have it in between each of the numbers

Comment: @JMoravitz yes thats how I want it, thank you.

Comment: Rephrase this sequence as recurrent one: $u_0=0$, $u_{n+1}=2u_n+2^n$. Maybe it may help.

Comment: @Oleg567 what do you mean?

Comment: $u_0=0$, $u_1=2\cdot 0+2^0=1$, $u_2=2\cdot 1+2^1=4$, $u_3=2\cdot 4+2^2=12$, $\ldots$

Comment: That's what I can do with formatting.  I'm about to leave for dinner, so I don't have the time to think of the answer to your actual question, but I wish you luck.

Comment: @Oleg567 that's what I was asking.

Comment: But not all $u_n$ are correct here: I see $2\cdot 452+128 = 1032 \ne 1028$. Some corrections are here...

Comment: The first one is Pascal's Triangle rotated by 45 degrees.

Comment: @hypergeometric that was an accedent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence can be described by formula:
$$
u(n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
n\cdot 2^{n-1}, \qquad\; n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6;\\
n\cdot 2^{n-1}+4, \;\; n=7,8,9,...;\end{array}
\right.
$$

$u(0)=0$, $u(1)=1$, $u(2)=4$, $u(3)=12$, $\ldots$, $u(6)=192$;

$u(7)=448+4$, $u(8)=1024+4$, $\ldots$, $u(13)=53248+4$.

Comment: I think the method you use leads to formula $u(n)=n\cdot 2^{n-1}$. This correction "$+4$", maybe, is after small mistake in calculations in pyramid.

Comment: how did you get that? did it just fit, or did you actually work it out.

Comment: After recurrent relation, form of formula must be like $u(n)=2^n\cdot O(n)$,where $O(n)$ was chosen manually.

Comment: sorry, I made a calculation mistake,just the top formula is correct, I'll leave your question as the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the number of edges in N-dimensional cube:

```
4 = 1 * 2 + 2 (square)
12 = 4 * 2 + 4 (ordinary cube)
32 = 12 * 2 + 8 (4-D cube)
80 = 32 * 2 + 16
192 = 80 * 2 + 32
448 = 192 * 2 + 64
1024 = 448 * 2 + 128
2304 = 1024 * 2 + 256
5120 = 2304 * 2 + 512
11264 = 5120 * 2 + 1024
24576 = 11264 * 2 + 2048
53248 = 24576 * 2 + 4096
114688 = 53248 * 2 + 8192
245760 = 114688 * 2 + 16384
524288 = 245760 * 2 + 32768
```